# Get access from tables with parent child relationship

Tags: sql, postgresql, common-table-expression, recursive-query

I have the following schema to store the node hierarchy and access to node for a role.
A role inherits access to child nodes from the access set to parent node unless it has entry in accessdetails table.

I want to get the descendents, level and access for a particular node for a given role. In this case the role is 1 and parent is 'b'.

SQLfiddle [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/a455f8/8/0)

```
CREATE TABLE hierarchy
    (parent varchar(1), node varchar(1))
;

CREATE TABLE accessdetails
    (role integer, node varchar(1), access integer)
;
    
INSERT INTO hierarchy
    (parent, node)
VALUES
    (NULL, 'a'),
    ('a', 'b'),
    ('b', 'c'),
    ('c', 'p'),
    ('p', 'q'),
    ('q', 'r'),
    ('b', 'd'),
    ('d', 'j'),
    ('a', 'e'),
    ('e', 'f'),
    ('f', 'x')
;

/*
0-no,1-r,2-w,3-full
*/

insert into accessdetails
  (role, node, access)
values
  (1, 'b', 3),
  (1, 'c', 2),
  (1, 'p', 0)
 ;
```

Following query returns the level and descendents properly but am not able to get the correct access.

```
with recursive
descendants as
  ( select parent, node as descendant, 1 as level,
     (select access from accessdetails where node=hierarchy.node and role=1) as access
    from hierarchy where parent = 'b'
  union all
    select d.parent, s.node, d.level + 1, 
   (select access from accessdetails where node=s.node and role=1) as access
    from descendants as d
      join hierarchy s
        on d.descendant = s.parent
  ) 
select descendant, level, access 
from descendants
order by parent, level, descendant ;
```

```
Current output:
descendant  level   access
c           1   2
d           1   (null)
j           2   (null)
p           2   0
q           3   (null)
r           4   (null)
Expected output:
descendant  level   access
c           1   2
d           1   3
j           2   3
p           2   0
q           3   0
r           4   0
```

How do I achieve this?

Final [solution](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/08ccb/17) with minor modification to schema:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you start your hierarchy with nodes having `b` as a parent.  These are nodes `c` and `d`.  Node `c` has access `2` explicitly assigned, but node `d` does not.  The query does not "see" the access of `3` assigned to node `b` because that row is not included in the query.

This query is how I would approach the problem.  It generates the entire hierarchy and then limits it to rows that have `b` as the first node in its path.

[Fiddle Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/a455f8/21)

```
with recursive descendants as ( 
  select h.parent, h.node as descendant, 1 as level, ad.access,
         array[h.node]::text[] as path
    from hierarchy h
         left join accessdetails ad on ad.node = h.node
  union all
    select d.parent, s.node, d.level + 1, 
           coalesce(ad.access, d.access), d.path||s.node::text
      from descendants as d
           join hierarchy s
             on d.descendant = s.parent
           left join accessdetails ad on ad.node = s.node
  ) 
select descendant, level, access, path
  from descendants
 where path[1] = 'b'
 order by parent, level, descendant ;
```

Comment: Isn't the query very expensive in this case, since the entire hierarchy is generated before the limit is applied?

Comment: @user3902153  Yes.  It can be.  If you want to reduce the amount of work, specify `where h.node = 'b'` in the CTE, but if you had a default `access` level defined at the very top of the hierarchy, then the only way to carry it down the hierarchy is to begin your recursion at the root.

Comment: the root node of a given role will have an entry in the accessdetails table, in this case it is b. Hence in my case, adding the where clause in CTE, works appropriately. Thank you, marking your answer as the solution.